# Cplex Python Error Getting Error in Basis Row Status

Tags: python, linear-programming, cplex

Statement `cplexProblem.solution.basis.get_row_basis()` gives the following error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Checked the code a bit and in _procedural.py , there seems to be a bug in the **getbase_r** . Please check the last line **return LAU.array_to_list(cstat, numrows)** , should it not be **return LAU.array_to_list(rstat, numrows)**

```
_procedural.py
def getbase_c(env, lp):
    numcols = CR.CPXXgetnumcols(env, lp)
    cstat   = _safeIntArray(numcols)
    rstat   = LAU.int_list_to_array([])
    status = CR.CPXXgetbase(env, lp, cstat, rstat)
    check_status(env, status)
    return LAU.array_to_list(cstat, numcols)

def getbase_r(env, lp):
    numrows = CR.CPXXgetnumrows(env, lp)
    cstat   = LAU.int_list_to_array([])
    rstat   = _safeIntArray(numrows)
    status = CR.CPXXgetbase(env, lp, cstat, rstat)
    check_status(env, status)
    return LAU.array_to_list(cstat, numrows)
```

Has anyone seen this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there was a bug there. That was fixed in CPLEX 12.7, I believe. Which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You found a bug, indeed. The issue was fixed in CPLEX 12.7.1.

However, as a workaround, you can use [Cplex.solution.basis.get_basis()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex._internal._subinterfaces.BasisInterface-class.html#get_basis) instead.  For example:
`cplexProblem.solution.basis.get_basis()[1]`

In fact, the `get_row_basis` and `get_col_basis` methods were deprecated in 12.7.1, in favor of using `get_basis` (see the deprecated section of the release notes [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.1/ilog.odms.studio.help/CPLEX/ReleaseNotes/topics/releasenotes1271/deprecated.html)), and subsequently removed in 12.8.